# django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Unknown field(s) ( message) specified for Message in django error

Tags: python, django

form.py  ( consider all imports ) can anyone point out error that we  i am getting message is unknown field in django

```
class emailForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Message
        fields = ['receiver','subject' ,' message']
        labels ={'receiver':'receiver','subject':'subject' , 'message' : ' message'}
        widgets = {'receiver':forms.TextInput(attrs={"class":'form-control'}),'subject':forms.TextInput(attrs={"class":'form-control'}),'message':forms.Textarea(attrs={"class":'form-control'}),}
```

models.py ( consider all imports ) can anyone point out error that we  i am getting message is unknown field in django

```
class Message(models.Model):
    sender = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='sender')
    receiver = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='receiver')
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=1200)
    message = models.CharField(max_length=1200)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

 
    def __str__(self):
        return self.message
```

views.py ( consider all imports ) can anyone point out error that we  i am getting message is unknown field in django

```
def home(request):
form = emailForm(request.POST)
if request.method == 'POST' or 'GET':
    if form.is_valid():
        email= request.POST.get('email')
        subject = request.POST.get('subject')
        message = request.POST.get('message')
        user = Message(receiver=email , subject=subject ,message = message )
        user.save()
        form =emailForm()
        return redirect('inbox')
        # return redirect('addpost.html')
    else:
        form =emailForm()
return render(request,"home.html",{'message':form})
```

error traceback the

```
xception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/threading.py", line 950, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/threading.py", line 888, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 53, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 118, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 392, in check
    all_issues = checks.run_checks(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 70, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs, databases=databases)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 13, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 23, in check_resolver
    return check_method()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 408, in check
    for pattern in self.url_patterns:
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 589, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 582, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 790, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/Users/sundaradhikari/Desktop/voice/voicemail/voicemail/urls.py", line 24, in <module>
    path('',include('mailapp.urls'))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/urls/conf.py", line 34, in include
    urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 790, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/Users/sundaradhikari/Desktop/voice/voicemail/mailapp/urls.py", line 6, in <module>
    from mailapp import views 
  File "/Users/sundaradhikari/Desktop/voice/voicemail/mailapp/views.py", line 12, in <module>
    from .forms import emailForm
  File "/Users/sundaradhikari/Desktop/voice/voicemail/mailapp/forms.py", line 11, in <module>
    class emailForm(forms.ModelForm):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/forms/models.py", line 268, in __new__
    raise FieldError(message)
django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Unknown field(s) ( message) specified for Message
```

Comment: Please share the **Full Error Traceback**

Comment: i have added error traceback

Answer (score 3):

The problem is caused by an extra space in `' message'` in `emailForm` in forms.py on this line:

```
fields = ['receiver','subject' ,' message']
```

Remove the space so the line becomes:

```
fields = ['receiver','subject' ,'message']
```